# jquery select all except ids in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some Ids in an array and I want to select all elements in the div except those that have the same Ids in the array.

is it possible to do this using a jquery feature and without having to loop the array and compare the Ids.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector, and join the array right there in your selector:

```
$('div :not(#' + array.join(', #') + ')');
```